# Condition satisfied by curves with acceleration perpendicular to constant vector

Tags: differential-geometry, curves

> Let $a:I \to \mathbb{R}^3$ be a normal curve with unit speed. Denote $\kappa(t), \tau(t)$ the curvature and torsion of $a$ and assume that $\kappa(t) > 0$ and $\tau(t)\neq 0$ for all $t\in I$ and that there exists a constant vector $v$ satisfying $\langle a''(t), v\rangle = 0$ for all $t\in I$. Show that
> $$\tau(t) + \left( \frac{\kappa(t)}{\tau(t)}\right)^{'} = 0 \quad \forall\; t\in I$$

**Attempt:** My idea here is to use Frenet-Serret equations. $\langle a''(t), v\rangle = 0$ implies that $\langle N, v \rangle = 0$. From here neither writing
$$v = \langle T, v\rangle T + \langle B, v \rangle B$$
nor differentiating the initial equality led to something meaningful. Another idea was to note that $N(t)$ is actually a planar curve so it must have torsion equal to zero but the calculations led to nothing.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Have you observed that $\langle T,v\rangle$ and $\langle B,v\rangle$ are both constant? This makes the curve a generalized helix, so $\kappa/\tau$ is constant. I do not believe the result is correct.

Comment: @TedShifrin I was just about to post that. $a(t) = (\cos t, \sin t, t)$ is an obvious counterexample.